# storage mapping function for multi array in C

Tags: c, arrays

When you have a two dimensional array like

```
int matrix[P][Q];
```

you can acces the element on place [i][j] be using one of these options:

```
matrix[i][j]
*(matrix[i]+j)
*((*(matrix+i))+j)
```

But I would like to acces the element by using a storage mapping function, I tried this

```
*(matrix+Q*i+j)
```

but this seems to give the location in the memory and not the element I want from the matrix. I think I'm pretty close but I can't figure out how to adjust this so it gives the result I want.

Comment: Not sure that I understand why you can't use `*((*(matrix+i))+j)` instead.  Why are you wanting to use this particular mapping function?

Comment: @RichardChambers It's because I'm learning for my exam, it could be a question to explain why `*(matrix+Q*i+j)` seems equivalent but isn't and to adjust it so it does work.

Comment: @Levi Because `matrix`, `matrix[i]` and `matrix[i][j]` are three different types, thus incrementing each of them has completely different meaning.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be But I'm trying to use pointer arithmetic on a 2D array. So I'm always selecting the element on place (i,j) from the same matrix.

Comment: @Levi Yes, and that's why it doesn't work. Because the element of an 2D array is a 1D array. So for example by adding 1 to the array you are jumping Q elements.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be oh okay, so do you have any idea how you can add 1 without jumping Q elements? Would it help to use sizeof()?

Comment: @Levi The second element in the array can be accessed: `*(matrix[0]+1)` or `*((*(matrix+0))+1)` or `*((*matrix)+1)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with the matrix as a 1D array, you'll need to cast it to one.

The following test program does the job:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    #define P 7
    #define Q 4
    int matrix[P][Q] = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4}, { 5, 6, 7, 8},
                        { 9,10,11,12}, {13,14,15,16},
                        {17,18,19,20}, {21,22,23,24},
                        {25,26,27,28}};

    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Q; ++j)
        {
            int val_1d = *(((int*)matrix)+Q*i+j);
            assert(matrix[i][j] == val_1d);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this code is invoking undefined behaviour. Access beyond valid indices of an array is not defined.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? The example above doesn't access beyond valid indices. It does however assume that the memory is allocated in P number of blocks with length Q (which the OP also seem to assume). The sources I found related to array memory allocation seemed to agree with that (none of them refuted it).

Comment: No sub-array of matrix has indices upto Q*P-1. Just a side note, this code also breaks strict aliasing rules.

Comment: And exactly where does the code access beyond Q*P-1?

Comment: I'm also curious about the strict aliasing, gcc seems unable to catch it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, it would seem that in C, pointers `int *` and `int **` would be considered compatible. So not breaking strict aliasing in C, but definitely in C++.

Comment: Are you sure about that? GCC seems fine with it as C++ as well, in fact `int arr[P][Q]...` and `int arr[P*Q]...` generate the exact same assembler.

Comment: GCC is relatively lenient towards strict aliasing, but I'm confident that `int*` and `int**` are incompatible types in C++. Also strict aliasing generally licks in when you are using some sort of loop construct (some variable that shouldn't have been get cached).

Answer (score 0):

```
*(matrix+Q*i+j)
```

is interpreted as

```
matrix[Q*i+j]
```

`matrix` is not a pointer to `int` but a pointer to `int[Q]`. You need to cast `matrix` to `int`.
`*((int*)matrix + Q*i + j)` should work.

Comment: Your explanation sounded good to me, but when I tested it, I still got a random integer and not one from the matrix. It looks to me that there's no way to get the element by using only 1 time * and without [ ].

Comment: Try `for(i = 0; i < P*Q; ++i) printf("%d\n", *((int *)matrix + i));` This gives you the idea about how values in `matrix` are stored.

Answer (score -1):

2D C arrays are not always allocated on continuous memory blocks so you cant calculate the offset of their elements from just one pointer.

EDIT: this is the case only for dynamically allocated arrays, as @ElderBug pointed out when arrays are declared like this:

```
int array[X][Y]
```

they are allocated to continuous memory blocks.

Comment: 2D flat arrays (like `int array[X][Y]`) are ALWAYS continuous

Comment: @ElderBug you're right, was talking about dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: @ElderBug Well, he is sort of correct. The standard mandates that 1D arrays are continuous. However a 2D array could theoretically have padding between the 1D blocks without breaking the standard. It would be weird, but it's possible.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be **6.2.5 Types 20** _An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
particular member object type, called the element type_

Comment: Yes I'm talking about static arrays, not dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yup. But there is nothing mandating that the size of the 1D array is exactly N*element_size. So when the element type is the 1D array, the 1D array can contain a padding on the end.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be A 2D array is a 1D array of 1D arrays. What you are saying is non-sense. Padding is unrelated to arrays, if there is padding, its part of the element size.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be no, when T name[dim1][dim2], standard says object `T`(T is continuous.), not  means `T[dim2](1D Block)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What? But that's what I'm saying. T is continuous array of 1D arrays. There is no space between the 1D arrays. What the standard doesn't mandate is that the 1D arrays take up precisely `N*sizeof(elem)` bytes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It is generally irrelevant since using out-of bounds indices for arrays invokes undefined behaviour, so it doesn't matter how the sub-arrays are actually organized.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be 1D-array even or even 2D-array are continuously  is T (in this case `int`). There is no gap between the int element.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The element of a 2D array is a 1D array, not T. Simply because there is no such thing as a 2D array in the standard. Every array is a 1D array of something.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Standard says array of T.  T is continuous. It is not to say that the change by dimension. Is it(your say `not T`) possible to show by  say  of standard?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Christ. Say T is an array of 7 chars, padded to 8 bytes. T is continous. Array of T is continous, but there is one byte padding between each line.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be [TEST CODE](http://ideone.com/4YEGv1)  If After the padding is present in the array sizeof (string [0]) must be the 8.
functions like qsort if it comes to 8 will not work correctly.

Comment: I seem that One system may be exist  such as `sizieof (char [7])` become 8.
However, it can not be used methods such as `sizeof(a) / sizeof (*a)` to count the elements.

Comment: In other words it can be said continuous if  `sizeof (char [n]) == n(sizeof(type [n])==n*sizeof(type)` is true.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes. That is a reasonable assumption. However still not a guarantee. Btw. you cannot use qsort to sort multi-dimensional arrays. That violates strict aliasing.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be `qsort` does not know whether it is multi-dimensional. BTW "still not a guarantee" What reason that is not a guarantee?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY And you don't know what strict aliasing is. However it turns out that this is actually a moot point, since strict aliasing would only be violated in C++, not in C.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be  Does it exist boundary problem in the case of `int a[n][m];` ..`sizeof(a) == n*m*sizeof(int)` is true?

Comment: if the problem exists `int (*a)[m] = malloc (n * m * sizeof(int));`, it will cannot apply. but it can `int (*a)[m] = malloc (n * sizeof(*a));`